# Changing AID of an Installed Package or Applet in JavaCard?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, globalplatform

As mentioned in the title, I want to know if there is any way to change the AID of a Java Card **applet** or a **package**, after **install for load** or after **install for install** process?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. AID is a unique identifier and it cannot be changed. The only way is a reinstallation.